# Checking values in variables and show one or more of the highest ones

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm learning Javascript and I'm trying to build a website with a tool for musicians.
Here's something I can't figure out how to achieve using normal conditions, comparisons, etc.

Let's say I have 5 variables:

```
a = 0;
b = 0;
c = 0;
d = 0;
e = 0;
```

Now using some checkboxes, the variables now update to:

```
a = 0;
b = 3;
c = 1;
d = 3;
e = 0;
```

So I want variables **b** and **d** to become the prioritized variables, because they are both the variables with the highest value (3).
Or if only 1 variable would get the highest value, that single variable would be priority, for example:

```
a = 0;
b = 7;
c = 1;
d = 3;
e = 0;
```

In this case variable **b** would become prioritized, because it's the highest number.

What's the best way to accomplish this?
Basically I want to compare all values and first check what's the highest value?
Then, the variable or variables with that value would be assigned for example a different name or value. For example if each variable was a musical note name (C, D#, F, G, Ab), then I would add a + sign to their name (e.g. D#+ and G+).
This part, what the end result will be on the front end, is not that relevant, to be honest. I just want to understand what kind of logic goes behind this and how can that be achieved?

Thank you! :)

**EDIT:**
So one approach I was thinking of was:
First, gather all the variables and sort them from highest value to lowest:

```
b = 3;
d = 3;
c = 1;
a = 0;
e = 0;
```

First, set b to TRUE.
Then compare d with b. If it's the same number, set it to TRUE, else set it to FALSE. Do the same for c and compare it to B. Compare a with b, e with B.

I end up with all the TRUE variables at the top and all the other ones as FALSE.

Is this a good approach? Is there another easier alternative?
This works with 5 variables, but what about if I had 100?

Comment: Maybe if we can have look at the frontend. it will sure be helpful. A codesandbox ?

Comment: I still don't have the frontend. I'm just working on the "logic" behind the whole process first. Basically the whole "program" will be: a musician ticks some checkboxes based on the chords of the song they are listening to. Based on those chords, it will show the keys that fit those chords. Each key has 7 chords that fit into them. There are 12 keys total. So the key(s) with the highest number of chords associated, will be visible to them. Hope it makes sense

Comment: I was brainstorming and one of the options would be to gather the 5 variables and first order them from highest value to lowest. Then compare the second variable and see if it's the same value as the first (the one with the highest value in that sorted list). If it is, it's "True", if not, it's "False". Then compare the third with the first, the forth with the first, etc. Would this be a good approach?

Comment: So what you can do is, store them in an array, Find the maximum value using the Math.max( ...arr ), then you can apply a map function to get the index values that match the max value you found at the previous step. Then you can have the index of the max elements. So now you just need to attach the keys from the particular index from the parent array, And thus with this approach you can actually have a single bloc of code to perform all the final steps..

Comment: Thank you @SARANSURYA. I will save that info here on my notes :) That's still out of my current knowledge, but I will get there ;)

Comment: @SARANSURYA Reading it again, I think I understand the process. I just need to get familiar with `Math.max` and all that. But it sounds simpler than I thought :)